# Source of שלום זכר

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, baby-infant

What is the earliest source for the מנהג of making a שלום זכר?
Anything earlier than שולחן ערוך will make me happy to be honest...

Comment: http://5tjt.com/the-shalom-zachar-an-overview/ Trumas Hadeshen 269, Rabbeinu Tam, among other rishonim, are mentioned there.

Comment: Please define "making a שלום זכר". Does there need to be chickpeas? Does it have to be Friday night?

Answer (score 5):

See Gemara Baba Kamma 80a

> מכי אתא רב לבבל רב ושמואל ורב אסי איקלעו לבי שבוע הבן ואמרי לה לבי **ישוע הבן.**  ‏
>
> Tosfot:
>
> לבי ישוע הבן. ...ור"ת פי' שנולד שם בן ועל שם שהולד נושע ונמלט ממעי אמו כדכתיב והמליטה זכר (ישעיה סו) נקט לשון ישועה והיו רגילין לעשות סעודה: ‏
>
> Yeshua Haben, according to R"T is a meal before the Brit Mila.

See Sde Tsofim [on the daf](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4215&st=&pgnum=310) the last paragraph in name of Trumat Hadeshen 269, that it is a Seudat Mistva

See also Wikipedia ([Shalom Zachar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalom_Zachar))

Comment: The above source states the reason for making a Seudah. It doesn't explain the origin of why it is done on the Shabbat before the Brit (why can't it be done on a weekday?) and why it got the name "Shalom Zachar". I edited the above assuming that "BK" means Baba Kamma. If I'm wrong, please correct.

Comment: @DanF you are right, Rabbenu Tam doesn't mention shabbat, it may be as the "Brit Yitschak that the Marocains make the night before the brit". But the poskim Trumat Hadeshen and further, see the link for "Sde Tsufim" keep it as the source. So the reference is not mine, I assume that someone can not agree